# How to get value of JSON object which includes arrays in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
{
    "dogs": 
          [
            {
             "type": "labradoodle",
             "color": "black",
             "name" : "Blak"
            },
            {
             "type": "poodle",
             "color": "pink",
             "name" : "Colins"
            }
          ],
      "cats": [
            {
             "type": "Maine Coon",
             "color": "grey",
             "name" : "Kitty"
            }
        ]
}
```

How I can use `whereJsonContains` for getting animals by type? For example that I need all poodles with pink color?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database type and version of Laravel you're using, the syntax and available helpers for 'whereJsonContains' will be different. You haven't provided either piece of information, so alternatively you could do something like this once you consume your Json.

```
foreach($animals as $animal => $attribute){
// Check key, value data here for what you want.
}
```

See: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries)

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry. It is Postgres, and the last version of Laravel. I just thought that I can use like whereJsonContains('dogs->type','poodle') but It does not work. Your solution is right for me but for that at the first I need to get all animals and only after that I can filter it. But I want to filter it and only after that get animals